# In DAX how to filter table1 value&sum to be calculated only if table2 boolen value set during period

Tags: dax, filtering

I've been few days already tried sort this issue with no success (not even from chat GPT;)eriod. I have linked tables stocks, dates

I have an action table2, from which I try to use trigger "sold" to calculate dividents from another table1 only if stock sold on same p

```
**  dates        type   stock   price**
    1.1.2022    sold    alpha   100
    11.1.2022   buy    beeta    200
    21.1.2022   buy    gamma    300
    1.1.2023    sold    beeta   100
    11.1.2023   sold    alpha   300
```

and table1 I use to sum dividents in various way

```
    **dates     stock   divident**
    21.1.2022   alpha   10
    31.1.2022   beeta   20
    10.2.2022   gamma   30
    20.2.2022   zorro   20
    2.3.2022    zeta    20
    21.1.2023   alpha   10
    21.1.2023   beeta   20
    31.1.2023   gamma   30
    10.2.2023   zorro   20
    20.2.2023   zeta    20
```

In BI I can summarize OK all stocks "sold" and dividends in given period, but calculating in another measure dividents of only sold stocks fails

```
    **year     stock    sold value   all dividents  sold dividents**
    2022 sum            100           100           *this sum dont work*
    2022       alpha    100         10                  10
    2022       beeta                 20  
    2022       gamma                 30  
    2022       zorro                 20  
    2022       zeta                  20  

    2023 sum             400         100            *this sum dont work*
    2023       alpha    300         10                  10
    2023       beeta    100         20                  20
    2023       gamma                 30  
    2023       zorro                 20  
    2023       zeta                  20
```

I manage to create in table2 a boolean if stock sold, but do not know how to apply it properly. E.g. **the sum of sold stocks dividents is either empty or sums erroneously all sold stocks dividents during all years.**
e.g. to count sum of sold stocks I use: soldprice= CALCULATE(SUM('table1'[price]),filter(all('table1[Type]),('table1'[Type]="sold")))